# Iterative calculation for time series using loops in R

Tags: r, loops, iteration, lag, lead

My data is composed of 30 years of observable values for 17 samples. The **test** dataframe below minimizes the sample depth to three but retains the time series length. Currently, my code only returns the desired calculation for the first column when I anchor the year to 1991. Note: 1991 is the first possible calculation due to lags in the formula.  I would like to be able to run the calculation iteratively for all years for each sample.

```
test <-tibble(Year=c(1988:2017),value=c(runif(30)),value.2=c(runif(30)),value.3=c(runif(30)))
index=1991
x <-test[test$Year ==index,"value"]
lag.3 <-test[test$Year ==index-3,"value"]
lag.2 <-test[test$Year ==index-2,"value"]
lag.1 <-test[test$Year ==index-1,"value"]
lead.3 <-test[test$Year ==index+3,"value"]
lead.2 <-test[test$Year ==index+2,"value"]
lead.1 <-test[test$Year ==index+1,"value"]
average_lag_3 =(lag.1 +lag.2 +lag.3)/3
average_lead_3 = (lead.1 +lead.2 +lead.3)/3
var.x <- ((((lag.3 +lag.2+lag.1)*(x-average_lag_3)^2)/2)+(((lead.3 +lead.2+lead.1)*(index-average_lead_3)^2)/2))/2
dscore <- average_lag_3 - average_lead_3/(sqrt(var.x)*sqrt(2/3))
```

Comment: What's the desired output? Do you only care about `dscore`, or do you want `var.x` too? Anything else?

Comment: in the `var.x` computation, do you need to use `index - average_lag_3` or did you mean to say `x-average_lag_3`??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want the `dscore` back, I put your code in a function. The only changes I made where replacing `"value"` with `column` and `test` with `data`, to match the argument names I chose:

```
## you should choose a better name than `foo`...
foo <- function(column, data, index = 1991) {
  x <- data[data$Year == index, column]
  lag.3 <- data[data$Year == index - 3, column]
  lag.2 <- data[data$Year == index - 2, column]
  lag.1 <- data[data$Year == index - 1, column]
  lead.3 <- data[data$Year == index + 3, column]
  lead.2 <- data[data$Year == index + 2, column]
  lead.1 <- data[data$Year == index + 1, column]
  average_lag_3 = (lag.1 + lag.2 + lag.3) / 3
  average_lead_3 = (lead.1 + lead.2 + lead.3) / 3
  var.x <-
    ((((lag.3 + lag.2 + lag.1) * (x - average_lag_3) ^ 2) / 2) + 
       (((lead.3 + lead.2 + lead.1) * (index - average_lead_3) ^ 2) / 2)) / 2
  dscore <- average_lag_3 - average_lead_3 / (sqrt(var.x) * sqrt(2 / 3))
}

## We can then apply this function to all the column names except the first one:
sapply(names(test[-1]), foo, data = test)
# $value.value
# [1] 0.4992873
# 
# $value.2.value.2
# [1] 0.1238061
# 
# $value.3.value.3
# [1] 0.8298876
```

Similarly, we can loop over years and columns:

```
## Generate combinations
my_years = 1991:1994
my_cols = names(test[-1])
year_col = expand.grid(year = my_years, column = my_cols)
## Make a place for the results
year_col$dscore = NA

## Do the calculations
for(i in 1:nrow(year_col)) {
  year_col$dscore[i] = foo(year_col$column[i], index = year_col$year[i], data = test)  
}
year_col
#    year  column     dscore
# 1  1991   value  0.4992873
# 2  1992   value   0.389055
# 3  1993   value  0.4510184
# 4  1994   value  0.5745417
# 5  1991 value.2  0.1238061
# 6  1992 value.2 0.08960943
# 7  1993 value.2  0.2999356
# 8  1994 value.2  0.4479232
# 9  1991 value.3  0.8298876
# 10 1992 value.3  0.7607005
# 11 1993 value.3  0.6520277
# 12 1994 value.3  0.5498328
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. Much appreciated!

Comment: I am getting Error: Can't subset with `[` using an object of class factor, when running the last loop.

Comment: Can you confirm that it runs on the tibble you provided in the question? Those are the results that I show. If that's the case, then my question is to you what is the difference between the (working) sample data and the (not working) real data? Look especially at the column classes - do you have a `factor` column that should be numeric? Or do you need to exclude more than just the first column from the loop?

Comment: I use `names(test[-1])` to use all the column names except the first one. You might need to adjust that to run on only the appropriate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using Base R, you could write a function that returns all the values:

```
lead_lag_mean <- function(x, n){
  
  lag <- base::prop.table(c(y <- numeric(n),0, y + 1) )
  lead <- base::rev(lag)
  
  lead_mean <- stats::filter(x, lead)
  lag_mean <- stats::filter(x, lag)
  
  var_x <- (lag_mean * (x - lag_mean)^2 + lead_mean * (x - lead_mean)^2)*n/(n-1)/2
  dscore <- (lag_mean - lead_mean) /sqrt(var_x * 2/n)
  data.frame(lead_mean = lead_mean, lag_mean = lag_mean, var_x = var_x, dscore = dscore)
}

lapply(test[-1], lead_lag_mean, n=3)
```

try this on your test and check whether the first row matches your results